.fbx export causes "glowing" textures
I just started using Blender today. I'm trying to export an item as .fbx, as it has textures. However, whenever I do this, it causes an odd glowing effect.

What could be the cause of this? Every time I export, I check the mesh in Paint 3D to insure that the texture has been added properly. I don't know if it could be the program itself or an issue with the textures. None of the textures are transparent.

Materials are the least cross-compatible thing in 3D modeling software. There may not be a direct fix for this, but there’s almost certainly been workarounds tried and true before now. Good luck.

Does this answer your question? .fbx export why there are no materials or textures?
